# Facebook page serving, bookmark ajax hashes, but no redirection when JS disabled

Tags: ajax, url, hash

I would be grateful to find out some really weird things I have seen on facebook URLs

If I bookmark this URL (found when JS is enabled)

http://www.facebook.com/HumanRightsWatch?v=app_2344061033#!/HumanRightsWatch?v=box_3

Then disable JS

I then proceed to revisit the same url

e.g. http://www.facebook.com/HumanRightsWatch?v=app_2344061033#!/HumanRightsWatch?v=box_3

and its sends me here:

http://www.facebook.com/HumanRightsWatch?v=app_2344061033&_fb_noscript=1

There is no redirection happening, im checking headers and getting a 200 ok

My question is, how is this done? I guess it cant be using JS redirection because thats disabled. Is there any other form of redirection that it could be using without showing it in the headers?

Yours, deeply confused :#

Cheers

Ke

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ahh i see, its using a meta refresh tag